Memory usage php Script as Service Ubuntu
I have a php script running as a service on ubuntu, it's an infinite loop that does external checks to save to the mysql database.
It consumes up to 1GB of memory, checking using the HTOP command
Running the get_memory_usage commands with each iteration of while, I have different values, when I don't pass the true parameter to get the Real usage, the value remains stable, however with the true parameter, it grows with each iteration.
Mem: 3.49 mb - 132 mb 02
Mem: 1.01 mb - 132 mb 03

Mem: 4.66 mb - 146 mb 02
Mem: 1.01 mb - 146 mb 03

Mem: 5.01 mb - 148 mb 02
Mem: 1.01 mb - 148 mb 03

Mem: 6.12 mb - 148 mb 02
Mem: 1.01 mb - 148 mb 03

Mem: 6.4 mb - 162 mb 02
Mem: 1.13 mb - 162 mb 03

I have already separated the execution block into a single function outside of while, and called gc_collect_cycles(), but it didn't solve the problem.
$loop   = Array();
gc_enable();

function execute(&$loop, $rep_server){

    foreach($rep_server->objetos as $server){
        
        $dates = calcDateGetData("","",0,false,false,2,40);
    $loop[$sid]['data_inicial']         = $dates[0];
        $params['dataCadastroInicial']  = $loop[$sid]['data_inicial'];
        $js_ar  = $server->sendRequest(REQUEST::ObterClientesServicos,$params);

        if(isset($js_ar["dados"])){
            if(count($js_ar["dados"]) > 0){
                foreach ($js_ar["dados"] as $key2) {
                  $cliente              = new ClienteServico();
              $cliente->uid_            = DB::toUid_($server->id, $key2['id_servico']);
                  $remoto[] = $cliente;
                }
            }

            $repOs->objetos =    $remoto;
        $repOs->updateAllChanges($repAll);
        }
    }
   ...
   ...

   echo "Mem: ".convertBytes(memory_get_usage())." - ".convertBytes(memory_get_usage(true))." 02 \n";
}

while(true){

    
    echo "Mem: ".convertBytes(memory_get_usage())." - ".convertBytes(memory_get_usage(true))." 01 \n";
    execute($loop, $rep_server);
    gc_collect_cycles();
    DB::getInstancia()->close();
    echo "Mem: ".convertBytes(memory_get_usage())." - ".convertBytes(memory_get_usage(true))." 03 \n";

    $c = count($opts);
    if($c > 1 && $opts[$c-2] == "-d" && is_numeric($opts[$c-1])){
        echo PHP_EOL." SLEEP FOR ".$opts[$c-1]."(s)".PHP_EOL;
        sleep($opts[$c-1]);
    } else
        return;
    
    echo "\n";
}

I don't think there's a memory leak, but that the memory freed by PHP is not being freed in Ubuntu, any ideas?

To test if the memory is actually freed by PHP you can try pushing the memory load on your OS (maybe open a lot of browser tabs if there's a UI). Sometime the OS will not bother releasing the memory allocated to a process if it doesn't really need the memory for anything else.

This conference talk is from a few years ago, so some of the details may be out of date, particularly with changes in PHP 7 and 8, but it has some useful tips on the different places you can measure memory allocation, and what they mean: https://youtu.be/sm1HUrnsxLI

You must to use generators instead of ordinary loop. Because generators don't create new object in every iteration of a loop. They are reusing the same object in each iteration. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php
Nevertheless, this is a common task of collecting metrics. Such needs are solved with the help of a lot of specialized software (for example: Prometheus, telegraph, zabbix agent, etc.).
